# How to get centroid of arc in React Native?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, react-native

I have some arc's in React Native and I would like to get their [centroid](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape/blob/master/README.md#arc_centroid) (middle point) for labeling purposes. They are generated using `d3.shape.arc()`. They are drawn with SVG using the data generated by arc.

I am trying to follow [this example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbhall88/b2504f8f3e384de4ff2b9dfa60f325e2) (I also found [this](https://swizec.com/blog/how-to-make-a-piechart-using-react-and-d3/swizec/6785) but cannot get anything to work either). It is in React.js so I will have to convert it to React Native as I have done in the past but I am stuck.

I've tried things like:

- `this.middle = this.arc.centroid();`
- `this.middle = this.arc.centroid(this.props.arcData);`
- `this.middle = d3.shape.arc().centroid(this.arc);`
- `this.middle = d3.shape.arc().centroid(this.props.arcData);`

where it says `//My attempts here` below:

```
export default class Arc extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.arc = d3.shape
            .arc()
            .outerRadius(this.props.outerRadius)
            .innerRadius(this.props.innerRadius)
            .cornerRadius(this.props.cornerRadius)
            (this.props.arcData);

        //My attempts here
    }
    .
    .
    .
    render() {
        return (
            <G>
                <Path d={this.arc} fill={this.props.color} />
                <Polyline ... /> //This is what I'm trying to draw eventually
            </G>
        );
    }
}
```

It either tells me that it is not a function for the first 2 attempts or returns an array with two NaN values for the second 2 attempts. I've run into this before, because these variables are not objects we can call functions on and React Native doesn't have DOM elements for select, append, attr, and all that jazz. I was able to work around it in the past but I am stuck this time.

Are there other ways I can successfully get the centroid of the arc in React Native?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually figured out the next day that you could just substitute the whole expression to create an arc again for lack of a variable.

```
this.points = [
    d3.shape.arc().outerRadius(this.props.outerRadius).innerRadius(this.props.innerRadius).centroid(this.props.arcData),
    d3.shape.arc().outerRadius(this.props.radius*0.95).innerRadius(this.props.radius*0.95).centroid(this.props.arcData),
    pos
];
```

The first element is the original arc and the second is the outerArc based on the example linked in the question.

I then draw the Polyline with points:

```
<Polyline points={this.points} />
```

Hope this helps anyone looking to use centroids in React Native. If you run into trouble with midAngle or NaN with the points, let me know in the comments or something.